# Как сделать, чтобы синий цвет подстраивался под размер картинки и всегда покрывал её?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как сделать, чтобы синий цвет подстраивался под размер картинки и всегда покрывал её?

```css
.intro {
    max-width: 1920px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.intro__bg {
    max-width: 1920px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(34, 40, 75, 0.86);
}

.intro__bgimg {
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <div class="intro__bg"></div>
  <img src="https://img3.akspic.ru/originals/8/6/668-tma-les-chernyy-derevo-priroda-2560x1440.jpg" alt="Intro"     class="intro__bgimg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать ее фоновым изображением, и сверху наложить маску-цвет полупрозрачную

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.intro {
    max-width: 1920px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.intro__bg {
    max-width: 1920px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.intro__bg:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(34, 40, 75, 0.86);
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}
.intro__bgImg {
    max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
    <div class="intro__bg">
        <img src="https://img3.akspic.ru/originals/8/6/668-tma-les-chernyy-derevo-priroda-2560x1440.jpg" alt="" class="intro__bgImg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нет, не то. Если взять меньше картинку или просто с этой картинкой приблизить экран, то картинка сжимается.

Comment: @roderann видимо не верно понял вопрос. Отредактировал, так ?

Comment: Спасибо большое)